# Navigate in man intro

Tags: terminal

I was checking the `man intro` command in the terminal, and the section "SEE ALSO". How do I access `man(1)` or `intro(4)` for example?

[image: Sample man page]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't navigate *within* `man`, you need to access all man pages directly from the shell.

- `man man` for the manual page of the `man` command
- `man 4 intro` for the intro page of section 4 (which is not installed, so ìntro(1)` is incorrect)
- `man 8 intro` for the intro page of section 8

PS: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections for an explanation of the various sections.

Comment: why section 4 is not installed and what's the link with intro 1 ?

Comment: @TmSmth only Apple knows that.